# javaScript Object for each loop

Tags: javascript, json

I am having problem with Object for..each loop

Please see Snap.

I am getting `point1` undefined.

Please suggest me.
[image]

```
    var applicationMap = jsonContent.application.map;
    var jsonContent = ConfigurationJSON.getData();
            var pointTypes = {};
            for(var app in applicationMap){
                pointData = this.getApplicationPoints(app);
                for (var point1 in pointData){
                    //jsonContent.point.map[point1];
                    pointTypes.push(TranslationJSON.translate(jsonContent.type.point.map[point1.type].name));
                    // Create the list of point types with checkboxes.              
                }
            }
```

Comment: **Pleasseeeeeee** post the code in the question as well as the screenshot.

Comment: Dude, your snap shot is illusive and not readable to us. Copy your code and paste directly here instead.

Comment: @Lion: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HeJdh.png

Comment: Post the code in the question. The screenshot doesn't even show the whole of the highlighted line. @Lion: if you right-click on the image you will - at least, in Chrome - get an option to open it in a new tab and then the path will be shown (that was the only way I could read it).

Comment: Just saw the updated question: the code you've posted doesn't match your screenshot, but ignoring that, what do you think is in `pointData`? Is it an object? Could it have properties that actually are `undefined`? I'd suggest liberal use of `console.log()`...

Comment: @Lion right click on image and copy link location.

Comment: Add `console.log(point1);` beneath `for (var point1 in pointData){` and show us the output.

Comment: @Stefan it prints `1389427585719546608` and  now i get value :). That's weird.

Comment: Thanks all of you and specially @Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just put `consol.log(point1)` beneath `for(var point1 in pointData){`

and check again it prints and also given me a value.
[image]

Comment: Ok. Then please check the object **pointData** thoroughly. I think there are correct keys and one or more wrong keys.

Comment: But your watch window shows that there are only two key value pairs. Is this working now ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that keys in **pointData** are strings.

```
pointData = {"1389427585719546608":{name:"Rajesh"}, "1389427585719546609":{name:"Vinod"}}

for(var point1 in pointData){
   console.log(point1);
   var item = pointData[point1];
   console.log(item.name);
}
```

This should give logs

```
1389427585719546608
Rajesh
1389427585719546609
Vinod
```

Please confirm this.

Comment: `point1.type` occurs within the for (var point1 in pointData)`. Obviously, `point1` is not an ordinary string. What's the value of this answer?

Answer (score -1):

As per the code you have posted, you didn't close the outer for loop.

Comment: That would cause a syntax error, rather than a variable being undefined.